# Support Fabric components (React Native stripe)

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments

I'm using RN 0.71.4 and when I'm trying to add stripe element like `CardField` I am facing below issue that is not Fabric compatible yet.

I tried to turn off `newArchEnabled` like comments on Github, but it also raise another compile errors.

Are there any solutions to use another element or library? I need to use stripe element ans wondering how can I solve it using another module or configuration.

Thanks!

[image]

https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native/issues/1275

Answer (score 1):

As comments on the Github issue the new architecture hasn't been supported yet. The only path forward is turning off the new architecture, and resolve the "other compiling error" you have. Stripe RN SDK has been working before this architecture so it's the correct direction to go.

Comment: I agree with you @orakaro, and it saves my time :) It seems I may need to contact stripe support team to ask they are planning to upgrade sdk as I do want to keep my RN version up to date.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed this issue to be fixed by disabling `newArchEnabled`.

android/gradle.properties:

```
# Use this property to enable support to the new architecture.
# This will allow you to use TurboModules and the Fabric render in
# your application. You should enable this flag either if you want
# to write custom TurboModules/Fabric components OR use libraries that
# are providing them.
newArchEnabled=false
# -> this here ^^^^^
```

- clean gradle and rebuild app.

[image]